# Media query for landscape view

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I need query for mobile iPhone 5  and galaxy S4 landscape view...

Her is my code but something is not ok here.

```
    @media 
(max-width : 800px){
// style

@media 
 (max-width : 360px){  
//style
```

On resolution 360 evrything is ok,  What i need to enter for landscape view.

Here is [EXAMPLE](http://stefanvblog.com/category/news/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone):

**iPhone 5 in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) 
{ 
   /* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Samsung Galaxy S4 Landscape (from [here](https://gist.github.com/mrlami/6072981))

```
@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi)
  and (device-width: 1920px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `device-aspect-ratio` for iPhone 5 - it does not have a 16:9 aspect ratio. It is in fact 40:71.

iPhone 5 only:

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /*style here*/
}
```

Galaxy S4 only:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    /*style here*/
}
```